# JavaScript: differences between `Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)` and `Object.prototype.toString(foo)`

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a better way to check data types in JavaScript. I know there are `typeof` and `instanceof` operators but they all have some pitfalls. And I found there is a method `toString` on `Object.prototype` can solve this very elegantly because it can differentiate all of the types by returning different strings based on `Symbol.toStringTag`

```js
Object.prototype.toString.call(function(){})  // "[object Function]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(null)   //"[object Null]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined) //"[object Undefined]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(/123/g)    //"[object RegExp]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date()) //"[object Date]"
Object.prototype.toString.call([])       //"[object Array]"
```

And it also works on primitive types.

However one thing I don't quite understand is that if we leave out `.call` from `Object.prototype.toString` and we just invoke it as in `Object.prototype.toString()` it returns  `[object Object]` for everything.

So my question is what is it that makes `.call` result in correct strings for types?

Comment: `call` binds `this` value to `toString` method, which itself doesn't take any arguments. That is, `Object.prototype.toString()` returns `Object.prototype` as a string.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate a bit more on it? I thought that `.call()` is equivalent to invoke a function just using parentheses

Comment: Nope, the first argument of `call` is the `this` value to bind to the function which is called. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we leave out `.call` and just invoke it as in `Object.prototype.toString()` it returns `[object Object]` for everything.

That is to be expected - you are calling that `toString` method (which ignores its argument, and depends only on the `this` context of the call) on the `Object.prototype` object.

You'll want to have a look at the [`call` method documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [how the `this` keyword works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In short:

```js
"use strict";
function demo(...args) {
  console.log(`this: ${this}, args: ${args}`);
}
const obj = { method: demo, toString() { return "the object"} };
demo(obj, 0);
demo.call(obj, 1);
obj.method(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`call()` is a method available on functions as functions are `first-class citizens` in javascript.

It sets the context of `this` keyword in your function `toString.call(argument1)`.
`argument1` is what the `this` keyword will point to.

Know more about `call()` function from [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to get a clear idea about how it works.